# How to combine JAVA code and HTML?

Tags: java, php, html

I'm a java noobie. I have a question.
In PHP you can do this:

```
<?php
for(i = 0; i<n; i++){ ?>
   <h3>Hello world!</h3>
   <p>This is a test app</p>
<?php } ?>
```

This way you will print those two html lines N times.
Is there any way to do the same in java? A way to "combine" both languages in a similar way?

Comment: Nowadays, it's more common to have a JavaScript script which communicates directly with the server via Ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Servlet:** [**More info**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/)

Within you Servlet file(.java)

```
out.println("<h3>Hello world!</h3>");
out.println("<p>This is a test app</p>");
```

**Scriplet:** [**More info**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/)

Within your JSP file(.jsp)

```
<html>  
<body>  
<% out.print("Hello World"); %>  
</body>  
</html>
```

However, the use of HTML within Servlet or Scriplets is not recommended. You should learn to use JSTL tags instead. [**More info**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but don't do it. They're called "scriptlets", and they're discouraged because they make code very difficult to test and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

There is very old approach in java web development. It has been used based on **jsp technology**. It is called *scriptlet*, but it is really out dated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what webserver you're using.  The closest to PHP would be **JSP** (Java Server Pages), which is a template language designed to build HTML.

**Java Servlets** can also do this, but are typically used with a web framework, like Spring or Struts, to automate away some of the boilerplate.